# Update datetime field with NOW() using PDO prepared statements

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm new to PHP/MySQL and trying to update a datetime field in MySql using PDO prepared statements. I pulled the NOW() out of the parameters and the script is executing without errors, but the field is not updating. If I run just the query directly in MySQL it updates fine. What am I missing?

```
$query = $db->prepare("UPDATE tablename SET inviteddate = NOW() WHERE email=:email");

$query->bindParam(':email', $email, PDO::PARAM_STR);

$query->execute();
```

Is there a better way to do this? Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure that `$email` has a valid value at the time you are binding the param?

Comment: Yes, I actually send an email to it in the line immediately before the section in question, so I know it's valid. That's why I'm so stumped.

Comment: If you send it immediately before, are you sure the default value of `inviteddate` is not just the current time before that, which means that if you run this query within 1 second of the first, there is nothing to be updated?

Comment: The default value of inviteddate is null, and it remains null after the script executes. Everything except this Update executes correctly.

Comment: See [Errors and error handling](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.error-handling.php), or else `print_r($query->errorInfo());`.

Comment: eggyal, thanks for pointing out an obvious troubleshooting step I overlooked. Basically, this revealed that the problem was that I forgot that I actually had to pass $db into this function as a parameter! Rookie mistake, but really appreciate the community's help as I learn. You guys rock.